# Update firebase users issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Want to update profile, started with email to get the hang off. Whenever I click on it to update the email, it adds a new UID for that email alone instead of adding it to the user profile with that UID. Really stuck now. I did have it working but cant seem to get back to it so must be an error here somewhere, thanks,
[image]

```
updateProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String updateEmail = emailTextView.getText().toString();
        user.updateEmail(updateEmail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("email").setValue(updateEmail);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

UPDATE

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            final String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

            Log.d(TAG, "USERID="+uid);
```

Doin this got me a UID from a completely different user! It did let me change the email for them when I did this but thats no use. Having similar issues deleting users. Is it an issue with a UID does it create a new one everytime they log in?

Comment: From the screenshot and code it looks like your UID changed. I'm not sure why that would happen though. Can you log the `user.getUid()` right before the call to `user.updateEmail` and also in the `onSuccess`, and then include the updated code and its logging output in your question?

Comment: Have updated now but still having issues

Comment: Sorry, that isn't what I was looking for. Can you change your existing code to log the `user.getUid()` right before the call to `user.updateEmail` and right inside its `onSuccess`? And then replace the existing code with the updated code, and its output. That way we can conclusive see if the `updateEmail` call changes the UID, which I don't think it ever should.

Comment: I actually managed to get it going not sure how I think was a issue way back in my registration activity. so just gonna delete this question, thanks though

Comment: Thanks for confirming Chris. Glad to hear that it doesn't seem to be a product bug after all. I voted to close as not reproducible.